# Is there a way to construct a bipartite $c$-expander graph, for a given $c >0$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs, bipartite-graphs, spectral-graph-theory

Suppose that $c > 0$ is a real number. Suppose that we are given integers $n > 0$ and $m > 0$. There are many bipartite graphs $G = (L, R, E)$ with $|L| = |R| = n$ vertices on each side and $|E| = m$ edges (let's suppose that we are given values of $n, m$ so that one exists). I am wondering whether there is a way to construct one (with high probability is good enough, if this construction is randomized) that is a $c$-expander in the following sense: for all $X \subseteq L$ (same for $X \subseteq R$) with $|X| \leq n/2$, we have that $|N(X)| \geq c|X|$.

If $m = dn$ for some constant $d$, then there is some value $c'(d)$ such that a random $d$-regular bipartite graph is a $c'$-expander. Is there a way to obtain a $c$-expander for any $c < c'$ in this model?

More generally, what are some ranges of values for $c$, $n$, $m$ for which this is possible?

Comment: An explicit expander construction with the corresponding proof would probably be too long for a post. There are many such constructions in the literature however, although there is still a gap between the best explicit constructions and random graphs. If you google "explicit expander constructions" you should come up with quite a few.

Comment: The details need to be worked out for this to be an "answer" here, but if you are fine with a randomized construction on a vertex-set $V$, then a multigraph on $V$ formed from taking the union of $d$ random matchings pf $V$; $d$ an integer satisfying $d \ge 3$, will do.

Comment: Thanks, I have been doing a bit of searching and have struggled to come up with exactly what I am asking, particularly as I'm interested in bipartite models. What is one example (maybe a reference, or name) of a construction, for fixed $n$, $m$, which can return a $c$-expander for a range of values of $c$?

Comment: Does searching "Ramanujan graphs" help?

Comment: Sorry, just posted my last comment after yours. What is the relationship between the $d$ for which we take $d$ random matchings, and the expansion factor in the resulting graph?

Comment: I believe the expansion-factor with random graphs can get close to $(d-1)$, i.e., sets $S$ with no more than $\epsilon |V|$ vertices have $(1-\epsilon')(d-1)|S|$ vertices outside $S$. The best with explicit constructions is weaker though, $d/2$ instead of $(1-\epsilon')(d-1)$, has been a longstanding upper bound.

Comment: Specifically for the union of matchings model you described? Or over all known constructions?

Comment: the expansion factor of $d/2$ is currently the bound for the best explicit constructions of $d$-regular expander multigraphs. The union of $d$ *random* matchings is what gives an expansion factor of something close to $d-1$ I think.

Comment: I think perhaps my question has been misunderstood. Fix $n$ and $m$. I am looking for a way, given some absolute constant $c > 0$, to construct a bipartite $c$-expander with $n$ vertices on each side and $m$ edges.

For the model you describe, the eventual number of edges is going to depend on $d$ (as with the $d$-regular model). I am looking for a way to control the amount of expansion in a graph with $n$ vertices on each side and exactly $m$ edges.